# Same value against each cell from a single column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one column like below:

```
Fruits:
Apple
Banana
Mango
Vegetables:
Broccoli
Tomato
Potatoes
```

I would like each value to have their parent name next to it in the cell like below:

```
Apple Fruit
Banana Fruit
Mango Fruit
Broccoli Vegetables
Tomato Vegetables
Potatoes Vegetables
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Easily done with Power Query (or VBA). Harder with formulas depending on your Excel version. Since this is not a free-coding service, please edit your question to show your attempts and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in column A, I am able to get the result with a helper column, by using the following formula in `B1`:
`=FILTER($A:$A,($A:$A<>"")*(RIGHT($A:$A,1)<>":"))`
This will result in your data excluding the titles (fruit, vegetable).

Then in `C1` use the following formula and drag down:
`=IFERROR(B1&" "&SUBSTITUTE(LOOKUP(2,1/(RIGHT(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&MATCH(B1,$A:$A,0)),1)=":"),INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&MATCH(B1,$A:$A,0))),":",""),"")`

Answer (score 1):

As per my below screenshot put below formula to B1 cell.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)=":",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),B1)
```

Then put following formula to C1 cell

```
=FILTER(A2:B9,RIGHT(A2:A9,1)<>":")
```

[image]

Comment: I need exactly what you have in column B. this formula isn't =IF(RIGHT(A2,1)=":",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),B1) helping so maybe you've added some magic there?