# Is it possible to reference to row number within spill function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

When trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741687/same-value-against-each-cell-from-a-single-column/65748592#65748592) I wanted to reference to data from a spill function to another spill function, or better yet to refer to the rows the spill function produces within the spill function itself.
I tried with some approaches and can refer to the spill data, but once I try to capture the row number of the data within the function it does not work how I wanted it to work.

Like in the question I used the following data in column A:

`Fruits: Apple Banana Mango Vegetables: Broccoli Potatoes`

I filtered it in column B with this spill function:

`=FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"")*(RIGHT(A:A,1)<>":"))`

This results in the fruit and vegetables without their parent name.

I then wanted to combine the values and the result of a lookup of the data in column B in column A from the start row up to the matching row of the data in column B with a condition (to find the closest row in column A, where the value ends with ":", to the row number of the value in B.
I used:
`=B1#&" "&LOOKUP(2;1/(RIGHT(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&MATCH(B1#;$A:$A;0));1)=":");INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&MATCH(B1#;$A:$A;0)))`

This results in error. (N/A).

Then tried:
`=B1#&" "&LOOKUP(2;1/(RIGHT(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&MATCH(B1;$A:$A;0));1)=":");INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&MATCH(B1;$A:$A;0)))`

This works, but the whole spill function keeps referring to match `B1` instead of `B1`, `B2`, etc..

Is it possible to refer to a changing row #, or to refer to the spill data within the function itself?

I'm able to get the spill data and it's row number in one go:
`=LET(x,FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"")*(RIGHT(A:A,1)<>":")),x&MATCH(x,A:A,0))`

This results in the fruits and the row number of the fruit:
[image: SpillAndRowNumber]
But if I try to use this row number in an INDIRECT function within that formula, it does not work:
`=LET(x,FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"")*(RIGHT(A:A,1)<>":")),x&INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(x,A:A,0)))`
[image: IndirectError]
Also, avoiding INDIRECT, using OFFSET ends in a #N/A error:
`=LET(x,FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"")*(RIGHT(A:A,1)<>":")),y,MATCH(x,A:A,0),z,OFFSET(A$1,,,y-1,),x&" "&LOOKUP(2,1/(RIGHT(z,1)=":"),z))`

Comment: 1st Note: `=FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"")*(RIGHT(A:A,1))` is not a complete formula. Maybe you meant `=FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"")*(RIGHT(A:A)<>":"))`

Comment: Correct. I missed copying that. Updated.

Comment: Do you accept a single function without helper columns using old excel function. (I don't have Office 365 in using Filter or Let function)

Comment: I can produce the answer already (which I answered in the mentioned topic). The intention of this topic is to refer to the row number of the spill range, row by row. Preferably from within the same function. The result would be 1 single formula in 1 cell creating a dynamic range which will grow/shrink along with the data without having to drag a formula down.

Comment: Is it not possible?

Comment: Is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per my below screenshot put below formula to B1 cell.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)=":",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),B1)
```

Then put following formula to C1 cell

```
=FILTER(A2:B9,RIGHT(A2:A9,1)<>":")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My intention is to dynamically refer to a row of a spilled range using a second spill function, or to the result of the function itself. My question is not focussed on getting the result, but more about the possibility of referring to row 1, 2, 3 of the spilled range from a new spill function. That way the data may be combined in 1 function without helper column(s)